# What is "accept_rate" in the Stack Exchange API?

Tags: support, discussion, api-v2, users

when I call the `/users` path, like:

[/docs/users-by-ids#&ids=1&site=stackoverflow](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users-by-ids#order=desc&sort=reputation&ids=1&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true)

In the reply, I get a field called `accept_rate`.

What is that field about?

Answer (score 3):

`accept_rate` is the internally tracked value of [the user's *Accept Rate*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16729/148310).  This is *roughly* a measure of how many of the user's questions have answers and where one of the answers was accepted by the user.

**For the actual details of how it's calculated**, read [the blog post announcing accept rate](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/).  In a nutshell:

- The user must have 4 or more questions.
- Only questions older than 3 days are counted.
- The question must have at least one answer to be counted. Answer score does not matter.
- Closed questions and Community Wiki questions do not count.

Also note that ["the community" decided not to publicly display the accept rate as of January, 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136951/148310).